# How to reach a Heroku deployment within Heroku bash or Heroku Scheduler

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to invoke a HTTP endpoint in my deployed Heroku app with Heroku Scheduler, which basically runs commands on Heroku `bash` at a fixed rate.

When I run `$ heroku run bash`, I can read my port with `echo $PORT` (let's say 5555). However when I try to access my webpage using `curl http://localhost:5555`, it does not work.

What is the way to reach to the app within Heroku bash **without using the app name**?

Comment: What kind of webserver do you start? Does it really run on `$PORT`?

Comment: Yes it does. I run it on `$PORT`.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind accessing your page? What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: I want to visit an HTTP endpoint to trigger a task. So I'll use that command with Heroku Scheduler cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run "heroku run bash" you are actually firing up a one-off dyno which - according to Heroku - is a different process (from the dyno running your "web" process type) running on a different runtime instance. Routing does not exist between processes, so the HTTP requests you're issuing will always fail.

Answer (score 1):

It's seems that there is no pre-configured environment variable.

However you can set it:

```
heroku config:add HEROKU_URL=http://<your app>.herokuapp.com
```